# What does "database is coherent collection of data with inherent meaning" means in database?

Tags: database

I have picked up the book named "Fundamentals of Database Systems, 3rd Edition" by Elmasri and Navathe to get a basic understanding first. I have started reading it from the first chapter.

> A database is a logically coherent collection of data with some
>   inherent meaning, representing some aspect of real world and which is
>   designed, built and populated with data for a specific purpose.

What does means above paragraph?

Comment: It means the authors were focused on giving a dictionary definition of databases that covered all the bases without telling you what real databases look like. Skip that, read on, go to the parts where they actually show a database (hopefully there are some) and come back to it later if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database is seen as a particular perspective on data and its representation in a framework of well-defined structures and interdependencies.

Breaking the definition down into parts:

- 'collection of data':
  What it's all about.
- 'with some inherent meaning':
  Mostly tautological, it would not constitute data otherwise. It shows, however, that databases do *not* exist to elicit the meaning of data. They may aid in doing so, though.
- 'representing some aspect of real world':
  Contestable, as databases may represent data over abstract domains like mathematics ( eg. a database of prime number twins ). Unless this also counts as 'real world', which would make this part tautological.
- 'logically coherent':
  Data items are related in a non-arbitrary way that allows reasoning about them. Often this aspect also includes comprehensiveness (as an objective at least) for the purpose at hand.
- 'for a specific purpose':
  The intended perspective on the data, which co-determines the nature of structures and relationships the database will be composed of.
  In particular the choice of representations and abstractions applied (eg. which parts of available data are dropped) depend on the intended purpose.
- 'designed, built and populated with data':
  Implies that databases comprise a model and use a technical base. It also implies that databases focus on the description of data.

The usefulness of such high-level descriptions is probably limited but may help to focus on some key issues wrt databases:

```
- Describing data                    \
- Structuring data                    > modelling data
- Relating data items to each other  /
- Reasoning over data
- Databases are tools
```

Comment: it is logicaly coherent collection of data. but u just explained collection of data. please add some more details to coherent ....

Answer (score 0):

My teacher wrote the answer for what is database in the slides, it says this

**Database:**

- a collection of data
- represents some aspect of the real world (database represent something in the real world)
- logically coherent collection (not a random collection)
- designed, built & populated for a specific purpose